# How to properly check if a registry key exists with c++?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

My goal is very simple, I just want to check if a registry key exists or not with C++. I couldn't find anything useful online. The following code compiles with no errors but I get the output "Not opened", and I know I have that registry key.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    HKEY hKey;
    if(RegOpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,TEXT("Software\\Oracle\\VirtualBox"),&hKey) == ERROR_SUCCESS)    {

        cout << "Opened";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "not opened";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would look for an API that searches the registry for a key.  If you do that first, you'll get better diagnostic information.

Comment: recommendation: Keep the return code and display it in the failure case so you know WHY the open failed. Usually some good information to be had.

Comment: I couldn't find anything, but RegOpenKeyEx opens a key and I suppose that if it can't open a certain key, it doesn't exist

Comment: if `RegOpenKey` succeeds you must call `RegCloseKey`.

Comment: Does the key exist, can you verify it with regedit?

Comment: you can use next code `BOOL IsKeyExist(HKEY hKey, PCWSTR lpSubKey)
{
 switch (RegOpenKeyExW(hKey, lpSubKey, 0, 0, &hKey))
 {
 case NOERROR:
  RegCloseKey(hKey);
 default:
  return TRUE;
 case ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND:
 case ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND:
  return FALSE;
 }
}`

Comment: Thank you all, i manage to get it working using RegOpenKeyEx :)

Answer (score 2):

The code you have is fine (though you should be using `RegOpenKeyEx()` instead, as `RegOpenKey()` is deprecated and provided only for backwards compatibility with 16bit code). You just need to pay attention to the return value. If `RegOpenKey/Ex()` returns either `ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND` or `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`, then the key does not exist. Any other return value means the key exists, and if the return value is `ERROR_SUCCESS` then you need to close the opened key, otherwise you don't have access to open the key even though it exists.